# show audio or video controller in dart

Tags: dart

I want to create a audio or video controller, but my current code only plays the content, nothing is shown to control it in my browser

```
#import ('dart:html');
void main () {
  AudioElement audio = new AudioElement();
  audio.src="http://slides.html5rocks.com/src/rushus-modal_blues.mp3";
  audio.autoplay=true;
  window.document.body.nodes.add(audio);
}
```

So how do you get Dart to show a controller for audio/video ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controls for audio/video are disabled by default. You will need to enable them

> audio.controls = true;

should do the trick.

Alternativly you can also build the audio source and controls settings from scractch, the following examples shows this and have been tested sucessfully with dart2js

```
var audioSource = new SourceElement();
audioSource.src = "http://slides.html5rocks.com/src/rushus-modal_blues.mp3";
audioSource.type = "audio/mp3";

var audio = new AudioElement();
audio.attributes["controls"] = "controls";
audio.nodes.add(audioSource);
window.document.body.nodes.add(audio);
```

There is more info on controlling audio [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp) and video [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp)